# How can I test the Api in Laravel via Postman?

Tags: laravel

I have a route like this:

```
Route::group(
[
    'prefix' => 'v1', 'as' => 'v1.',
],
static function () {
    Route::get('test', 'Api\TestController@test')->name('test');
    ///
```

How can I refer to this route so that it would work? I am trying to call this route in Postman http://localhost/api/v1/test but I get a 400 error

Comment: Is it a laravel generated 400 error or from the webserver you're using?

Comment: please add more details, which file contains this code? , is the function accessible?

Comment: You can check the log to get some extra information.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide enough information but check these just to be sure

1. Make sure these routes are listed among the api routes and not the web
2. If you're using artisan to serve your project, then ensure you're using the correct port in postman too eg http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/test
3. (Pretty obvious) Make sure you're sending a get request from postman
4. Check the function too to know if there's any problem. You could do an early return of a simple json response in the beginning of the function to make sure the route accessed the function at all